# How can you indicate a hidden button on the back of a device?

Tags: physical, discovery

The first time I used an iMac it was a terrible user experience - I couldn't turn it on. I was scouring the keyboard and running my hands around the edge of it looking for the on button, or some magic touch zone. The same goes for the Motorola Xoom Android tablet. It took me a long time to find the button the first time.

In general, is there any good way of letting users know where a button is on the back of a device?

Comment: You could have a video / animation play when the device is turned on showing you where the button is to turn it on.... oh wait.

Comment: There is a reason this doesn't happen very often in consumer electronics.

Comment: FWIW, the power button on an iMac is on the keyboard (or at least, that's where it used to be...)

Comment: @DA01 Not on a wireless keyboard it's not.

Comment: That's probably why there is often a 1 or 2 pages "startup" manual with most electronic products.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The problem lies in why the button was hidden in the first place. Presumably not for space-saving reasons, but for aesthetic reasons. This effectively **rules out any visual representation** on the device (otherwise, why not just put the button where people can see it?).

The only options at that point are to draw attention to the button in other ways, of which there are various.

- Detail the startup procedure in the user manual. Okay, so users don't read manuals, but a **quick-start sheet** might help some people.
- A **plastic sticker that can be removed** can be used to add a visual representation that doesn't interfere with the aesthetics of the design. It can simply be peeled off once the user knows where the button is.
- Another option is to **present the device to the user in such a way that the button can't be missed**. If the button is on the back, package the item so that the back is what the user first sees when they open the box.
- Related is the idea that you can **place required pieces of functionality physically next to each other**. Not many people complain that on/off switches on power supplies are hard to find, because those switches are usually next to the place you have to physically plug the cable into, massively increasing their discoverability.

Of course the other solution is to prioritise user experience over minor aesthetic matters and put the damn button on the front where people can see and use it. ;)

Comment: My problems with the iMac were probably due to not being the person who got it out of the box. All of these suggestions (bar the last) only work for the initial users, not any subsequent ones!

Comment: It's probably a bad design decision, like dhmholley said. The only thing I can imagine, would be that there are no buttons at all, just the ones on the back. every user would look at the front, the bottom, the sides, the top and sooner or later he would look on the back.

Comment: An excellent answer. That said, I would likely just stick with the decal.

Comment: The problem with "quick-start sheets" and more or less any other instructions are that most people never look at them. If a user finally turns to instructions the design could be considered broken.

Comment: I've often seen stickers to indicate important, easy to miss buttons like you point out in your second bullet. Just make them easy to remove. There's nothing worse than using goo-gone to remove a 1 cent sticker from a $200+ device

Comment: @fredley that's an important note too. My dad had me set up his new TV and then couldn't find the power button. It was of course right next to the power cable he had never plugged in

Comment: I've actually _returned_ devices that I later learned probably actually worked due to not reading 'quick start' guides. If I can't figure out how to do the most simple yet essential things with something (e.g. turn it on), it's going back to where I bought it. That being said, this is a really good answer as sometimes you just have to deal with a  really bad design decision you can't change in something you're shipping.

Comment: The older macs had a power button on the keyboard which could be used to turn the machine on.  If you want to keep the front of your device button free, this is another solution.  I admit looking at the keyboard is just as odd as looking at the back of the machine.

Comment: If you're going to going to put buttons on the back of the machine - make them big buttons with clear labelling. The original Classic Macs used to have a big rocker switch around the back that you could operate just by feel.

Comment: There is an argument to be made, rightly or wrongly, that moving the power button to behind the display may help subtly reinforce the notion that Macs are built to be left on (which enables all sorts of nifty features like network syncing/automatic updating/Back To My Mac).